# Don't make “destroy all my hat customizations” the default option

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash

I prefer wearing different hats on different sites. Different topics call for different personalities. Also I don't want to wear a hat on a site where I haven't earned it.

Can we please have the “only on this site” checkbox ticked by default? The current situation is that we have a big button for “destroy all my hat customizations, no undo, sucks to be you” and a small checkbox for “do the obvious thing and affect just the profile I clicked on”. That's backwards.

Even better, pushing a hat to all profiles shouldn't be done from some random profile, it should be a button (with confirmation) on http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/. But at least don't make it so easy to do accidentally.

Comment: You're way overthinking this. Hats are just a *for fun* event at the end of the year. They go away in early January. They aren't meant for the long term, and although the SE devs have stated they're building for annual re-use, this isn't really an issue that affects enough people over a great enough amount of time.

Comment: Related, in that a simple fat-finger mistake can destroy data across all of SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237649/147191.

Answer (score 11):

I'm going to argue that you are not the majority case, so the default will continue to be "wear on all sites". I have however made one change: We now remember if you've previously checked "only on this site" and keep it checked the next time you open your hat rack. This setting is stored in localStorage, so it's per-site (and per-browser).

Comment: If it was “wear on all sites where you haven't set a hat yet”, this would be a sensible default. But if I've already shown that I want to have per-site hats, it's bad. At least provide an undo button. Leaving the check box checked would be good enough if it was a global setting — a per-site per-browser setting is far too error-prone.

Comment: In case you missed it, looks like OP is appealing the rejection.