# How can I undo copying a profile to all SE accounts?

Tags: support, profile-page, linked-accounts

I like having different profiles on different sites. On some, I have quite a long bit of text. Just now, I accidentally hit the "Save Profile and Copy to all Accounts" button. How can I reverse that and recover my old profiles on all sites?

(This was on Biology SE. I didn't actually make any changes, and what I wanted to hit was "Cancel". A simple fat finger mistake on one site shouldn't irrevocably lose data across SE.)

Comment: You don't, I'm afraid. Not sure, but maybe profile info is also accessible using SEDE, so you can try to extract it from there.

Comment: AFAIK you can't. You'll have to re-edit them all manually.

Comment: This is aggravating, and while I haven't done it to myself yet I do fear misclicking and getting an unpleasnt, irreversible surprise.  I try to maintain my profile texts externally for just this reason.  But a history link for the "about" blurb, like we have for posts, sure would be helpful.

Comment: Also annoying, it happened just before an internet-free holiday, and by the time I came back the suggested solution of mucking about with the Data Explorer was no longer an option. @MonicaCellio.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there is no Undo option here.

You *could* query the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for your account description, or look at the Google Cache or Internet Archive copies of your profiles to recover the original text.

All but the Internet Archive are perishable caches; both the Data Explorer and Google Cache will eventually refresh their copy; the Data Explorer is refreshed every sunday.

For what it is worth, Google did [cache your previous English.SE profile](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Aenglish.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2F1696%2Ftrig), as did [the Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140704185225/https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1696/trig). Until this sunday, the [Data Explorer copy](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/215495) is also available.

I do hope for your sake that not all 118 of your accounts had unique descriptions!

Comment: GAAAH! They weren't all unique, but enough of them to be annoying. And I'll be away from a computer for the next week and a half.

Comment: @TRiG: Then take a look at the [Internet Archive of your accounts list](http://web.archive.org/web/20140710174433/http://stackexchange.com/users/72444/trig?tab=accounts) and see how many are cached from before today. Handle those that haven't been *first*, using Google or the Data Explorer.

Comment: @TRiG: I do spot a few that haven't been archived for example.

Comment: Weirdly, English and Christianity (but not SF&F) have been restored. I didn't do that.

Comment: @TRiG: Perhaps a side effect of the rollout of the new profile change-copy feature? See [New! Smarter profile creation and syncing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239619)